# How to use the 'hover' in html itself

Tags: css, hover

I am looking for a way to use the hover of css in html file just the way we use style="".
Please reply if anybody knows anything about it. I can not use a separate css file or a javascript.

Comment: why would you want to do that?? Do you not have access to the css file?

Answer (score 2):

you cannot simply specify hover inline instead you can write css code inside your html file and assign a class name to it and give the class name to your desired element:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.myClass{
color:red;
}
.myClass:hover{
color:blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: I believe you do not understand the difference between Inline and Embedded. What you have done is called embedded, what the person is looking for is Inline.

Comment: @cam yes but Nishad has specified in the answer `you cannot simply specify hover inline ` which is right and answer of the OP

Comment: If ask 2 + 2, i dont want to know 2 x 2, they may equal the same answer but you have changed the formula at which the question was asked.

Comment: @Cam Sometimes you need to take in the big picture. From what the OP asked, this might be a solution. This isn't math, it's art and science.

Comment: Hey Guys, Thanks for the answer. My problem is that i need to create UI components- accordion, button etc for a client. However the editor provided to me for coding does not allow me to include script tag. I allows me to use inline css and html only. Is it possible to create the component under such circumstances?